# Помогите прочитать кусок Си кода

Tags: c

Доброго времени суток, есть код такой функции:

```
void elf_exit(void)
{
    kill_data(&ELF_BEGIN, (void(*)(void*))mfree_adr());
}
```

Как прочитать второй параметр ф-ии kill_data?
На сколько я понимаю, тут происходит приведение типа функции mfree_adr() ?

Comment: Я правильно понял вы пишете ELF под sony ericsson ?

Comment: вам поможет [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=%28void%28*%29%28void*%29%29f)

Comment: @4BAL0V Я разбираю чужой эльф под SE. Очень приятно встретить человека, знающего, что это. С кодом не поможете?

Comment: Тут приведение типа результата вызова `mfree_addr`. / Очевидно, что она возвращает адрес функции, но вероятно ее прототип (точнее тип возвращаемого значения) описан иначе, чем второй аргумент `kill_data()`. А по сути, вызывается mfree_addr() и возвращаемый ей *адрес* передается в `kill_data()`

Comment: Подводя итоги, благодаря "VladD" и "avp" я(вроде бы) разобрался: второй аргумент функции "kill_data" вызывает функцию mfree_adr() и то, что она возвращает приводит к  указателю на функцию, которая возвращает void и принимает указатель на void. @avp, я вас правильно понял?

Comment: Да, совершенно точно (оказывается односложные комментарии система не принимает).

Comment: @avp Зато вышло очень литературно) P.S. Если бы написали ответ, а не комментарий - лучшим был бы ваш

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В этом вызове функции `kill_data`

```
kill_data(&ELF_BEGIN, (void(*)(void*))mfree_adr());
```

второй аргумент вычисляется как вызов функции

```
mfree_adr()
```

возвращаемое значение которой приводится к типу указателя на функцию

```
void(*)(void*)
```

То есть возвращаемое  знвчение - это указатель на функцию, которая имеет тип `void` и параметр с типом `void *`